# Unable to install eJabberd on centOS using the command line

Tags: centos, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to install eJabberd on my CentOS using ssh (putty).

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-on-a-centos-5-and-centos-6-vps#installing-ejabberd) article.

```
[root@server ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* EA4: 208.100.0.204
* base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
* epel: mirror.steadfast.net
* extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
* updates: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
repo id         repo name                                              status
EA4             EA4 ( EasyApache 4 )                                       23614
base            CentOS-6 - Base                                          6634+62
epel            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64         11484+746
extras          CentOS-6 - Extras                                             63
updates         CentOS-6 - Updates                                        741+67
repolist: 42536
[root@server ~]#
```

I had enabled EPEL. Then I am trying to install ejabberd. so below output comes

```
[root@server ~]# yum install ejabberd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* EA4: 208.100.0.204
* base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
* epel: mirror.steadfast.net
* extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
* updates: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
No package ejabberd available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@server ~]#
```

please help me. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another approach (the ejabberd package seems not to be on the EPEL; at least I can't find it on my CentOS 6.x linux box).

Login as root on the WHM server via SSH. Then do this:

```
wget -c https://www.process-one.net/downloads/ejabberd/17.01/ejabberd-17.01-0.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uhv ejabberd-17.01-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Of course if your OS is 32bit then you have to download the 32bit version of the .rpm package